# Unterschiedliche Bedeutungen von „Rechnung“

Tags: meaning

Im Wortfamilienwörterbuch der deutschen Gegenwartssprache von Gerhard Augst wird [„Rechnung“](https://books.google.ch/books?id=EYoryVG3HV0C&pg=PA1081&lpg=PA1081&dq=%22ergebnis%20des%20rechnens%22&source=bl&ots=7MzeExdLDF&sig=Ll0Uv0-KUlTa_eUs-5UrVHdOboQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL86GPwu7RAhXHiRoKHV0ZAYUQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=%22ergebnis%20des%20rechnens%22&f=false) u.a. als  „Vorgang des Rechnens“ und als „Ergebnis des Rechnens“ umschrieben.

Unter „Vorgang des Rechnens“ werden folgende Beispiele aufgeführt:

- eine einfache Rechnung
- die Rechnung stimmt, geht auf

und unter „Ergebnis des Rechnens“ diese:

- in der Rechnung steckt irgendwo ein Fehler
- nach meiner Rechnung (wie ich es einschätze) braucht er für den Weg drei Stunden.

Weshalb beschreibt „eine einfache Rechnung“ einen Vorgang? Ist das nicht vielmehr eine Rechen*aufgabe*? Unter einem Vorgang verstehe ich das Berechnen oder Ausrechnen. Und auch beim zweiten Beispiel („die Rechnung stimmt, geht auf“) sehe ich den Vorgang nicht.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wie schon erwähnt ist die Unterscheidung zwischen den beiden von deiner Quelle hervorgehobenen Bedeutungen eher schwach, aber auch ich kann einen unterschiedlichen Fokus ausmachen, wenn ich genau hinsehe (oder hinhöre). Deine beiden Beispiele und deine Kritiken werde ich separat behandeln.

> Eine einfache Rechnung.

Hier siehst du vor allem das Ergebnis des Vorgangs; möchtest es aber gleichzeitig mit einer *Rechenaufgabe* gleich setzen. Ich denke, dass du damit völlig in den Wald kommst. Zunächst zur Rechenaufgabe: Die ist, strikt semantisch gesehen, weder der Vorgang noch das Ergebnis sondern die Aufforderung, die zum Vorgang (und schließlich zum Ergebnis) führt. Üblicherweise stellt die Lehrerin eine Rechenaufgabe, *bevor* ihre Schüler zu rechnen angefangen haben; ebenfalls üblicherweise existieren gedruckte Rechenaufgaben auf Papier (ob in Büchern oder auf Arbeitsblättern) *bevor* sie den Schülern ausgeteilt werden, und diese zu rechnen anfangen. Die *Rechenaufgabe* beschreibt also etwas völlig anderes.

Es bleibt die Frage, ob mit einer *einfachen Rechnung* auch das Ergebnis gemeint sein kann, oder ob es der Vorgang sein muss. Ich meine, es kann sich ausschließĺich auf den Vorgang beziehen. Zu einem Ergebnis passt semantisch meines Erachtens weder die Zuschreibung *einfach* noch *schwer* – Ergebnisse können höchstens *richtig* oder *falsch* sein. Man vergleiche dies mit dem Ausdruck »eine schwere Geburt« — auch hier wird man eher denken, dass der Vorgang der Geburt beschwerlich ist, nicht aber das Ergebnis – das Baby – eine hohe Masse besitzt. Es macht aber durchaus einen Unterschied, ob man *im Vorgang* der Rechnung kompliziertere oder weniger komplizierte Schritte durchführen muss, *während* man gerade dabei ist, sie durchzuführen.

> Die Rechnung stimmt, geht auf.

Gerade bei »die Rechnung stimmt« kann ich durchaus auch den resultativen Aspekt (also die Betonung auf dem Ergebnis) sehen, wobei ich wieder glaube, dass sie eher im Hintergrund ist. Völlig im Hintergrund ist sie meines Erachtens aber bei »die Rechnung geht auf«. *Aufgehen* ist in sich bereits ein Vorgang. Wenn das Ergebnis des Rechenvorgangs aufginge, müsste man sich nicht die Frage gefallen lassen, wohin oder wozu? Betrachtet man allerdings den Vorgang, kann dieser durchaus aufgehen, und zwar so, dass sich alle losen Enden verbinden lassen und etwas stimmiges dabei herauskommt.

---

Ich denke, dass sich diese beiden Fälle leichter unterscheiden kann, wenn man statt des Substantivs *Rechnung* das Verb *rechnen* zur Hilfe nimmt. Wenn man von einer Rechnung spricht und das Verb im Präsens zu wählen wäre, spricht das dafür, dass der Vorgang im Vordergrund steht, während ein Verb im Perfekt (oder Präteritum) eher für das Ergebnis spricht. Ich deute die vier Beispielsätze folgendermaßen:

1. > So, wie ich es rechne, ist es einfach. (Eine einfache Rechnung → Vorgang)
2. > Wenn ich es so rechne, geht es auf. (Die Rechnung geht auf → Vorgang)

   - Man kann das natürlich auch in der Vergangenheit formulieren, dann aber durchgängig:

   > So, wie ich es gerechnet habe, ist es aufgegangen.
3. > So, wie ich es gerechnet habe, muss es falsch sein; da muss ein Fehler drinstecken. (In meiner Rechnung steckt ein Fehler → Ergebnis)
4. > Ich habe es ausgerechnet und er wird drei Stunden brauchen (Nach meiner Rechnung braucht er für den Weg drei Stunden → Ergebnis)

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt tatsächlich zwei unterschiedliche Bedeutungen von **Rechnung**, die in der Auflistung beim [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rechnung) deutlich werden:

> **Rechnung**
>   1. Formular, Papier mit der schriftlichen Aufstellung der gekauften Ware oder verrichteten Dienstleistung und der Angabe des Preises, der dafür bezahlt werden muss
>   2. Berechnung, Ausrechnung

Allerdings werden dort Deine Beispiele sämtlich unter der Bedeutung 2 gelistet.

Leider kann ich den DRM-geschützten Inhalt des von Dir zitierten Buches hier nicht aufrufen, so dass eine weitere Analyse, wie es dort zu den verschíedenen Bedeutungen kam, nicht erfolgen kann.

Auch in anderen Wörterbüchern (z.B. [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=Rechnung&MenuId=Search&service=canooNet&lang=de)) kommt nur die oben genannte Trennung vor.

Answer (score 2):

Ich stimme zu, dass die Unterscheidung keine sehr deutliche ist, die aber auch nicht aus der Luft gegriffen ist.

Für mein Gefühl geht es bei "eine einfache Rechnung" eben darum, wie man zum Endergebnis kommt. Und dass die Rechnung einfach ist, bedeutet meistens dass der Vorgang des Rechnens einfach ist, weniger, dass das Ergebnis einfach ist. Daher ist es schon sinnvoll, dass man Rechnung in diesem Fall as den Vorgang bezeichnend ansieht.

Beim zweiten Beispiel "die Rechnung geht auf" geht es wieder um den Vorgang, der in diesem Fall reibungslos und ohne Probleme abläuft. In diesem zweiten Beispiel ist auf jeden Fall auch das Ergebnis der Rechnung enthalten: Die Rechnung muss abgeschlossen sein, sonst wüsste man nicht, dass sie stimmt/aufgeht. Ich finde in diesem Fall wird mit "die Rechnung stimmt" mehr das Ergebnis betont und mit "die Rechnung geht auf" mehr der Vorgang an sich. Ich würde sagen, dieses Beispiel ist das problematischste, da es sich beiden Kategorien zuordnen lässt.

"In der Rechnung steckt irgendwo ein Fehler" betont dagegen deutlich das Ergebnis, da die Rechnung eben abgeschlossen sein muss, um das erkennen zu können. Ebenso für das letzte Beispiel, da ja auch hier das Ergebnis "drei Stunden" schon vorliegt.